# Change Binding value in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I need to make some complex binding in XAML. I have a `DependencyProperty` `typeof(double)`; let's name it `SomeProperty`. Somewhere in XAML code of my control, I need to use the whole `SomeProperty` value, somewhere only a half, somewhere `SomeProperty/3`, and so on.

How can I do something like:

```
<SomeControl Value="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=SomeProperty} / 3"/>
```

:)

Looking forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a division [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx):

```
public class DivisionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int divideBy = int.Parse(parameter as string);
        double input = (double)value;
        return input / divideBy;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

```
<!-- Created as resource -->
<local:DivisionConverter x:Key="DivisionConverter"/>

<!-- Usage Example -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource DivisionConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource DivisionConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource DivisionConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}"/>
```