# Combobox inside DataGridTextColumn not occupying it's parent Width

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="m_gridControl">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnCategory" Width="10*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <ComboBox Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=Width}" />
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

With this code, my `Combobox` doesn't fully occupy my `DataGridTextColumn`'s width. 
How do I set the properties to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<ComboBox Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=Width}" />
```

with

```
<ComboBox Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```

And your problem should be solved.

[Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in WPF is an indication while [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the real width of the element once it gets rendered.

Edit: To avoid the cropping on the `combobox`, you need to add a converter (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710521/change-binding-value-in-xaml)) to remove some pixels to it's width. If you need more help on how to do it, here is a [sample project I made](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DF74FFCC97DE92F2!127&authkey=!ALeXiwVhWrY9qbs&ithint=file%2c.7z) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Hi Luke,I got it.. is it possible to bind with (ActualWidth-10px). for that purpose am i supposed to create extra property? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer on SO can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710521/change-binding-value-in-xaml - just change the answer according to your needs.

Comment: Link to sample project combining the two solutions (VS 2013) : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DF74FFCC97DE92F2!127&authkey=!ALeXiwVhWrY9qbs&ithint=file%2c.7z